# How can I take a photo of a specific area on the camera screen in Android using CameraX?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-camera, android-camerax

I want to take photo of a specific area on the camera screen

I've tried to calculate and crop the photo I take I've tried some libraries but nothing I do is worked so I need your help because I'm stuck with this problem, it seems so easy to do it but it's really not.

Here's my XML Code of my camera activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/preview_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/transparentbackground"
            android:backgroundTint="#A4686868"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera_frame"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_camera_frame"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_capture_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/preview_view" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/zoom_seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/seek_bar_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/seek_bar_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/seek_bar_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/seek_bar_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_capture_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_capture_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/preview_view">

            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/image_capture_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/capture_btn_end_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="@string/capture"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/main"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closeCamera"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/main"
            android:background="@drawable/cross_close_icon"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/switchTextInputButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/baseline_text_fields_24"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/main"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

and here's my camera activity code:

```
class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCameraBinding
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
    private var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        binding.imageCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
            photoCapture()
        }

        binding.switchTextInputButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@CameraActivity, SensorAddManuelActivity::class.java))
        }

        if(allPermissionsGrantedByUser()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
            "We Have Permission",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, Constants.REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
                Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
            )
        }

        initializeCamera()
        cameraCloseButton()
        hideSystemNavigationBars()
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        counter++
        if (counter == 1){
            val intent = Intent(this, OpenCameraActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun hideSystemNavigationBars() {
        window.decorView.apply {
            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION){
            if(allPermissionsGrantedByUser()){
                initializeCamera()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGrantedByUser() =
        Constants.REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all{
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                baseContext, it
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }

    private fun cameraCloseButton() {
        binding.closeCamera.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this@CameraActivity, OpenCameraActivity::class.java))
        }
    }


    private fun photoCapture() {
        imageCapture ?: return

        val photoFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSS", Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpeg")

        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        imageCapture!!.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    try {
                        val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                        savedUri.path?.let { safePath ->
                            val file = File(safePath)
                            file.delete()
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@CameraActivity,
                        "Something went wrong!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }

                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    savedUri.path?.let { safePath ->
                        CameraPreviewActivity.path = safePath
                        startActivity(Intent(this@CameraActivity, CameraPreviewActivity::class.java))
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private fun initializeCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .build()
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
                val cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
                val cameraInfo = camera.cameraInfo
                cameraTouchControls(cameraControl, cameraInfo)
                sliderBarZoomFeature(cameraControl)
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun cameraTouchControls(cameraControl: CameraControl, cameraInfo: CameraInfo) {
        val listener = object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {

            override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {

                val currentZoomRatio = cameraInfo.zoomState.value?.zoomRatio ?: 0F

                binding.zoomSeekBar.progress = currentZoomRatio.toInt()

                val delta = detector.scaleFactor

                cameraControl.setZoomRatio(currentZoomRatio * delta)

                return true
            }
        }

        val scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(baseContext, listener)

        binding.previewView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val factory = binding.previewView.meteringPointFactory
                val point = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)
                val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point, FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF)
                    .setAutoCancelDuration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
                cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(action)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun sliderBarZoomFeature(cameraControl: CameraControl) {
        val zoomSlider = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.zoom_seek_bar)
        zoomSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                cameraControl.setLinearZoom(progress / 100.toFloat())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a full photo, and crop it.

Comment: thanks for advice i've already made it work like how I wanted to couple of weeks ago, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
    class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCameraBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // hide the action bar
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        // Check camera permissions if all permission granted
        // start camera else ask for the permission
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // set on click listener for the button of capture photo
        // it calls a method which is implemented below
        binding.cameraCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
            finish()
        }
    }


    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the
        // modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        )

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Set up image capture listener,
        // which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)

                    // set the saved uri to the image view
                    findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_capture).visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_capture).setImageURI(savedUri)
                    imageFile = savedUri
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                    finish()
                }
            })
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this@CameraActivity)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            val preview =
                Preview.Builder().build()
                    .also { it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider) }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

            // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
                )

            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    // creates a folder inside internal storage
    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()) mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    // checks the camera permission
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            // If all permissions granted , then start Camera
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                // If permissions are not granted,
                // present a toast to notify the user that
                // the permissions were not granted.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXGFG"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 20
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String? {
        val result: String?
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.path
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            val idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
            result = cursor.getString(idx)
            cursor.close()
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

and in my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".ui.camera.CameraActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottomsheet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_lens_24"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="Capture Photo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_circle_24"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/margin_medium_16"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/camera_capture_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_capture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium_16"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view11" />

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view11"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium_16"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_maincolor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/camera_capture_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBack"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnBack"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnBack"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnBack" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

update
here is pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOj1r.png)

Comment: my original code is working for taking photos this is not a problem, my problem is i've assigned a area with surface view on screen and when i take a picture i want to crop that area automatically and pass it on to my other activity that's it

Comment: imageFile = savedUri
                    val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                    finish()
this code i use savedUri in other activity call by companion object, so i take a pic then call onBackPress it work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into this [blog](https://medium.com/@sdptd20/exploring-ocr-capabilities-of-ml-kit-using-camera-x-9949633af0fe)

Comment: the link you share is broken i guess

Comment: Try now kaljal.

Comment: yes now i can see it thank you ill check that out

Comment: i have a question is this the only way to do this, i mean should i really use ml kits etc. because in my app i just need to take a picture and send that picture to server that does text recognition process i've already done that btw but i'm taking a full picture i just want to take a picture of a small square on the middle and do the same process like i'm currently doing with my original code up there

Comment: Ahh I think for taking picture alone mlkit is not needed. If you are scanning the qr code then you needed it. You can try without mlkit.

Comment: the camera code in the link should do the trick i guess because i'm not scanning anything it's just good old camera screen just takes photos that's it, but in the link you gave me the xml code seems to me a bit missing

Comment: I think you have missed the github link. Here the [link](https://github.com/doomSDey/OCR-Using-CameraX-And-MLKit) you can refer

Comment: i've made it but there's a little problem i'm trying to upload this cropped image to my server and it gave me FileNotFoundException, but the file path is correct i double checked i've tried clean project and rebuild after it but no use